# Errors when running unit tests with Roboelectric and android annotations

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-fragments, robolectric, android-annotations

I am using both Roboelectric and android annotations. Below is a simple test case I am trying to run:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk=21)
public class ProjectTest {

    public DashboardActivity_ activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(DashboardActivity_.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveAnswers() {
        assertThat(activity).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

However the test fails on setUp() with the following:

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file build\intermediates\res\merged\tst\debug\layout\dashboard.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class fragment

    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
```

It seems to be complaining about the XML layout file of my main activity. I doesn't seem to like the fact that I am using the < fragment > tag.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:title="Projects"/>
            <fragment
                android:tag="estimator_list_fragment"
                android:name="com.myapp.fragments.EstimatorListFragment_"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/estimate_list"
                tools:layout="@layout/estimate_list"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I looked a lot of other posts dealing with similar issues but none of the other known solutions have worked for me.

Comment: Is it multi-module project? If yes, check that BuilConfig is from correct module

Comment: Yes there are multiple modules.  I am not sure how I can check if its from the correct module.  Let alone how I could get the wrong one.

Comment: Check imports. It should package from the module

Comment: Normally Robolectric and AndroidAnnotations works together. Did you try to remove the fragment and run the test? Does your app work when you start in on real device? Do you see an warning that AndroidManifest.xml could not be found when running test? And is your fragment in the same module like the layout?